# abbrevs not expanding

Tags: abbrev

I have wrote the following abbrev definition file, and saved it as my_abbrev.el:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table '(
    ("else__" "else begin

end")
    ))

;; turn on abbrev mode globally
(setq-default abbrev-mode t)
```

I loaded it from my init.el:

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/my_abbrev.el")
```

However, when typing "else__" followed by a space, it is not expanding. when evaluating the expression list-abbrev, I see the following (as I expected):

```
(global-abbrev-table)

"else__"       0    "else begin

end"
```

What am I missing? why is my abbrev not expanding?

Answer (score 1):

If `(abbrev-table-get global-abbrev-table :regexp)` is nil the abbreviation before point is determined by `backward-word` and `forward-word` (see doc of `define-abbrev-table`).

But in most major modes the underscore `_` will not have word syntax.

First, we need to accept symbols as abbreviations. Abbrev-tables have a regular expression that matches abbreviations with [`looking-back`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html) in [`expand-abbrev`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expanding-Abbrevs.html):

```
(abbrev-table-put global-abbrev-table :regexp "\\_<\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)")
```

`expand-abbrev` is run in `self-insert-command`.
Relevant part of the doc of `self-insert-command`:

> Before insertion, ‘expand-abbrev’ is executed if the inserted character does
>   not have word syntax and the previous character in the buffer does.

So we have still the problem that after typing `else__` the char before point does not have word syntax. There are two ways of solving it:

1. You change your abbrev to something like `else_a` (the last `a` standing for abbrev). The last character before point is word consistent and the expansion will work after hitting space or newline.
2. Keep `else__` as abbreviation and use a similar solution as in [another answer about abbrev](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51220/2370):

```el
(defvar pre-self-insert-hook nil
  "Normal hook run before `self-insert-command'.")

(defun run-pre-self-insert-hook (&rest args)
  (run-hooks 'pre-self-insert-hook))

(advice-add 'self-insert-command :before #'run-pre-self-insert-hook)

(defun my-symbols-expand-abbrev ()
  "Also expand if the preceeding char has symbol syntax."
  (when (and (eq (char-syntax (aref (this-command-keys-vector) 0)) ?\s)
         (char-before) ;; avoid error at beginning of buffer
         (eq (char-syntax (char-before)) ?_))
    (expand-abbrev)))

(add-hook 'pre-self-insert-hook #'my-symbols-expand-abbrev)
```

Comments:

1. Consider to expand `else__` only in those major modes where it makes sense.
2. Consider using the library `skeleton.el` instead of `abbrev.el`. You can define skeletons with `define-skeleton` and use them with `skeleton-insert`. Skeletons allow you to place point easily between `begin` and `end`. Furthermore it allows you to indent and format the source code automagically.